# Session is not a struct?

Tags: session, coldfusion, cfwheels

The error I get is this:

`Element USER is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;`

The lines of code I get this error are when I do anything like this:

`SESSION.user.functionName()`

It's randomly and I assume is happening after the user's session is expired. My problem is first of all, isn't the `SESSION` scope always a structure? How/Why does ColdFusion think it's a string.

Regardless, my main problem is I am using CFWheels. All my controllers extend the main `Controller.cfc` of course and all my controllers (except the public one) filter through a `checkLogin` function. That function has this in it:

```
<cfif !structKeyExists(session, "user")>
    <cfif !structKeyExists(params,'layout') || params.layout EQ true>
                <cfset redirectTo(route="home",error="You must be logged in to continue.") />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset flashInsert(error="You session has expired and you must login to continue. <a href=''>Reload the Page</a> to login.") />
        <cfset redirectTo(controller="Shared",action="ajaxError") />
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

In this part of the function, I explicitly check if `user` exists in the `session` and if it doesn't one way or the other I'm sending them somewhere else. How on earth does the code get past this part to then fail when the `session` is somehow a string?

Not to mention there are various other places before I get to the error line where I'm making sure various things in the SESSION.user object are correct.

Comment: (Edit) The error message says the `user` element is string - not `session`. Granted error messages are not always 100% accurate. It may also mean the key does not exist at all. You get the same error from `session.someKeyThatDoesNotExist.functionName()`

Comment: Isn't it saying `user` is undefined in the object. The object being the class of String?

Comment: If you are right, if I change `<cfif !structKeyExists(session, "user")>` to `<cfif !structKeyExists(session, "user") || !isObject(SESSION.user)>`. Still, doesn't make any sense how it could have got past other parts of my code, using methods in the user object, just to get to the view and then fail, does it?

Comment: Is it possible that when you are setting the `user` object to the `session` that it's not finding the record and you are actually setting the `user.session` as just `false`?

Comment: Let's assume that I do. Before I get to this line in the view, I'm checking other permissions in the controller with a getter like similar to this: `SESSION.user.getProperty()`. That should throw an error. That method wouldn't exist. I don't however, I set `SESSION.user` in one single location in all of my code and it equals the return of the `init` function of the cfc. I'll look at the logic there and see if it's possible, still doesn't explain how it would get to that line though.

Comment: (Edit - Sorry comment lag) Think the test should probably be more like `<cfif !structKeyExists(session, "user")  || !isStruct(session.user)>`. Not sure how/where the key is set, but I guess it could still exist, but the value could still be something other than a structure. Where/how is the session.user variable initialized?

Comment: The `init` either throws an error or returns `this`. If an error is thrown all roads lead to `redirectTo(route="home")`. Right before I assign `SESSION.user = user` I have  `<cfif !isObject(user)>` to throw an error on the in case. `SESSION.user` quite literally has to be an object to get to that point in my code. It's blowing my mind.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the error is wrong somehow. I'm trying to recreate it with simple code on just a blank CF page and can't get the error to read that way.

Comment: Ah. I think I may have recreated it. On critical errors that may have like something messed up with permissions when logging in etc I do `structClear(SESSION)` and then redirect to home. If you do structClear and then try to reference the struct you get the same error. Still following all my code around, cannot see how it could get to the view if the struct was cleared.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those times when users are clicking shit all over the place hitting back/forward so many times it just breaks the internet.

Comment: When my code fails, it's never the user's fault.

Comment: Logging out in the middle of a asynchronous request is like a little bit their fault.

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was on ajax requests. Some ajax requests load reports and such that can take several seconds to query, especially before some caching takes place. If a user executes an ajax call and then logs out, technically the request could make it through all my permission checking to get to the controller (it takes just milliseconds) but in the controller while fetching data from the models the user is logged out.

Then by the time the view is ready to load, the Session is cleared. If I use anything from the session scope there, it errors out.

I think I'll fix this by adding a filter that runs after the controller action to check if the session scope is still there. If it's not I'll just abort the request. I don't have model logic in any of my views, but I sometimes reference methods in the `SESSION.user` scope. Probably not purist MVC.

On the cases where the logout happens before parts of the controller are complete, I'll just let those errors happen as they may and ignore them, knowing the user really isn't seeing it happen.

Comment: Grrr... it would appear the after filters run after the view runs. Not sure how to catch this.

Comment: Yet another reason to minimize your use of session variables.

Comment: You can put your code to run after session end in the ../wheels/events/onsessionend.cfm file. This will run your code as session ends. All values in session scope available there in argument scope.

Comment: That won't help. The only real fix is to not use my SESSION variables in the view files. Load any needed SESSION variables into the REQUEST scope or just variables in the controller. That way, if the SESSION ends before a SQL query completes it will all be ok. It's probably better to do that anyway. I agree about limiting the use of SESSION variables, but in this case, if I don't use a session, I'd have to hit my DB a lot more on tons of page requests for validation purposes. I could probably just copy the SESSION into a REQUEST.SESSION variable to have on hand.